# p:datatable rowkey not resolved with var

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm new to JSF and Primefaces and I'm trying to show a datatable of Orders. But anyhow, the rowKey cannot resolve the var attribute. Even the suggestions does not show the var field. Actually I did it exacly like in the primefaces showcase. Have I forgotten anything?

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="orderDT" 
                 var="order" 
                 value="#{orderModel.userOrders}"
                 selection="#{orderModel.tempOrder}"
                 selectionMode="single"
                 rowKey="#{order.id}"
                 style="margin-bottom:0"
                 scrollable="true"
                 scrollHeight="150">

        <f:facet name="header">
            Getätigte Bestellungen
        </f:facet>
        <p:column headerText="Bestellnummer">
            <h:outputText value="#{order.id}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Transportnummer">
            <h:outputText value="#{order.taId}"/>
        </p:column>                    
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Positionen">                           
            <p:dataTable var="pos" value="#{order.orderPositions}">
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{pos.grocery.name}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="Anzahl: #{pos.quantity}"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Betrag">
            <h:outputText value="#{order.invoice.amount}"/>
        </p:column>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton title="Bearbeiten" process="orderDT"  />
            <p:commandButton title="Stornieren" process="orderDT"  />
            <p:commandButton title="Rechnung anzeigen" process="orderDT"  />
        </f:facet>

    </p:dataTable>
```

---

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class OrderModel implements Serializable {

    private List<GroceryOrder> userOrders;
    private GroceryOrder tempOrder;

    // + getters & setters for userOrders, tempOrder, ...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed now, that it's still not resolving, but somehow it works even though. You can do it exactly as is the primefaces example.

Answer (score 0):

Rowkey expects a String, is it possible you're feeding it a number?

For reference, the Primefaces 6.2 documentation https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf

Comment: No, the rowkey is a String. I noticed now, that it's still not resolving, but it works now even though.